# Why did Bhishma go to bring Amba, Ambika and Ambalika from Kashi without the invitation of Hastinapura in swayamvar?

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma

Why did not Invitation to Hastinapur for Swayamvar, and why did Bhishma go there without Invitation?

Comment: It was kind a revenge game by both . Hastinapura was not invited for the Swayamvara of Amba ,Ambika & Ambalika by Kashya (king of Kashi). Because Shantanu rejected the proposal of marriage between sister of king of kashi and Bhishma previousely . So for king of kashi  it was insult & he did not invited Hastinapura , for taking his  revenge. On the other hand Bhishma felt that this  non invitation   is great insult of his kingdom . So he also wanted to take  the revenge . And he went to Kashi to abduct the princesses

Comment: Also take a look what Bhishma Says to the assembled kings - " But the sages have said that, that wife is dearly to be prized who is taken away by force, after the slaughter of opponents, from amidst the concourse of princes and kings invited to a self-choice ceremony. Therefore, ye monarchs, I bear away these maidens hence by force." - http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01103.htm

Comment: yes you are right @SwiftPushkar i can see Mahabharat (1988 TV series), but I need to source

Comment: Yes , i am looking for the source, may be it's possible that this is mentioned somewhere , but mostly it seems  the above is conclusion of scholars.